# Is it possible to change a Github package's description either at or after upload through Github Actions or the command line?

Tags: github, package, nuget, github-actions

I want to upload a nuget package to my Github repo's "Packages". This is to say I want to upload a nuget to Github Packages.

However uploading the package with the "dotnet nuget" command automatically sets the description of the package in Github to the description of the csproj file. The problem is that there is no other information about the package, specifically - release notes. That is why, considering my repo already shares the same description, I find the only way to inform users of what was changed in a given version is to write it in the "description" of the package on Github.

Is there a way to specify the description either when uploading the package or after that through use of Github Actions or a CLI or an API or whatever? Because I want it to be done automatically, rather than by hand for every version.

The documentation is silent on this matter.

Comment: I don't think it's possible after the package was uploaded. I couldn't find anything in the Packages an API docs.
I guess you'll have to programmatically edit the `.csproj` file before publishing.